# Python SQL Query Execution

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I trying to run a SQL query to perform a lookup between table and add column and update the result in new table in SQL and then pass the new table in pandas dataframe.

But when i execute i get the following error:

"

```
File "C:\Users\Sundar_ars\Desktop\Code\SQL_DB_Extract_1.py", line 27, in <module>
df1 = pd.read_sql(Sql_Query,conn)
  File "C:\Users\Sundar_ars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 602, in read_sql
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
  File "C:\Users\Sundar_ars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2117, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"
```

Below is the Code:

```
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd

SERVER_NAME ='DESKTOP-LBM9IMO\SQLEXPRESS'
DATABASE_NAME='721991dc-b510-40b2-ac5b-4d005a3cfd14'


conn = pypyodbc.connect("""
    Driver={{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}};
    Server={0};
    Database={1};
    Trusted_Connection=yes;""".format(SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME)
    )

Sql_Query = """
SELECT [EventFrequency].[ResultID]
      ,[EventFrequency].[EventFrequency]
      ,[EventFrequency].[ImmediateIgnitionFrequency]
      ,[EventFrequency].[DelayedIgnitionFrequency]
      ,[Result].[OnshoreCaseID]
INTO [%s].[SafetiRisk].[UpdatedEventFreq]
FROM [%s].[SafetiRisk].[EventFrequency]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [%s].[SafetiRisk].[Result]
ON [EventFrequency].[ResultID] = [Result].[ResultID]
""" %(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_NAME)

df1 = pd.read_sql(Sql_Query,conn)
print(df1)
```

Anyone can guide me what am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas-read-sql-query) assumes that your query returns rows - but your SQL query *modifies* rows (without returning any).

If you want to fetch the content of `[SafetiRisk].[UpdatedEventFreq]`, you should perform a`read_sql('SELECT *', ...)` on that table *after* executing your first query.